call to consteval function 'util::ConstevalHexDigit' is not a constant expression
i have bitcoin repo from tag v28.0, everytime i run cmake --build build -j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu), i keep getting the following error
bitcoin/src/uint256.h:133:19: error: call to consteval function 'util::ConstevalHexDigit' is not a constant expression

am trying to setup bitcoin as part of assessment for chaincode lab BOSS program.

What compiler are you using? You need at least GCC 11.1 or Clang 16.0 to build Bitcoin Core 28.0 (see list of dependencies: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v28.0/doc/dependencies.md)

The issue is the with the clang compiler. Use gcc as the compiler to build the code.
Install gcc from homebrew and then build the code with the following command specifying the path of the compiler to be used.
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-14 \
    -DBUILD_GUI=OFF -DWITH_BDB=OFF -DBUILD_BENCH=OFF -DBUILD_FOR_FUZZING=OFF -DBUILD_KERNEL_LIB=OFF \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TX=OFF -DBUILD_UTIL=OFF -DBUILD_WALLET_TOOL=OFF

